# Rotating image and its key points label in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0, data-augmentation

I am trying to add rotation to my dataset of images where the labels have some facial keypoints. tf.contrib is removed from tensorflow 2.0 and any other library like PIL does not work as I am using tf.data.Dataset.

I need angle rotated to be random while the same rotation needs to be applied to both an image and its keypoint labels as well. Is there a way to do this in tensorflow 2.0?

Below is the function I used:

```
def preprocess_data(image, angle):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [input_size, input_size])
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)

    image = Image.fromarray(np.array(tf.squeeze(image)))
    rotated = Image.Image.rotate(image, angle)

    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(rotated))
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, -1)
    return image

def load_and_preprocess_data(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    rotation = tf.random.uniform([1,1], minval=-60, maxval=60, seed=0)
    return preprocess_data(image, rotation)
```

Here I used PIL but it is not working when I try to map a tf.data.Dataset containing image paths to load_and_preprocess_data function.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do. You ask "I am trying to add random rotation" and "The rotation angle can't be random". What rotation do you want to apply? I assume that it can only be in 90,180,270 else you cannot represent it in a tensor? (unless you are also cropping??)

Comment: I think your question implies you could do this previously in tensorflow 1.x? If so could you post the code for that in your question to help us understand what you need?